# Integration by substitution $r=\tan\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's calculate the integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r^2)^{(n+1)/2}}dr.$$

then let $r=\tan\theta$,

according to my book, its result is

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-1}\theta d\theta.$$

but my calculation is

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}\theta \sin^{n-1}\theta d\theta.$$

Is my book wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is right. When you make the substitution $r=\tan\theta$, you have $dr=\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$.

So our integral is equal to
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{n-1}\theta}{\sec^{n+1}\theta}\sec^2\theta\,d\theta,$$
which simplifies to the book's expression.